# How to upgrade sqlite3 version in Python from 3.7.17 to > 3.8

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to launch new django app but get error- django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).

i already installed sqlite 3.27 and its in /usr/local/bin 
i tried suggested procedure here- [How to upgrade sqlite 3.8.2 to >= 3.8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508830/how-to-upgrade-sqlite-3-8-2-to-3-8-3) but no luck

[ec2-user@ip-]$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>

but when i do python3 manage.py migrate or runserver i get

raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)

I expect for django2 to take path of executable sqlite3 version that is sitting in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it definitely works. It's working on **Amazon Linux 2 AMI** :

```sh
wget http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/7/x86_64/RPMS/atomic-sqlite-sqlite-3.8.5-3.el7.art.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall atomic-sqlite-sqlite-3.8.5-3.el7.art.x86_64.rpm
sudo mv /lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6{,-3.17}
sudo cp /opt/atomic/atomic-sqlite/root/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /lib64
```

Check whether the version changed or not:

```
C:\Users\teamspirit>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.5'
```

Comment: Confirm, this is the easiest working solution.