# SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17) 0 0 vote positif

Tags: python, django, sqlite, deployment

I am trying to **eb deploy** some Django app.

But I face this error.

```
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
  backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
  return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 66, in <module>
  check_sqlite_version()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 63, in check_sqlite_version
  raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

I use Django3.1, I've tried downgrading to 2.1 but it won't work neither.

```
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable.
container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/db-migrate.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2021-06-22 15:34:35    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-06-22 15:34:35    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0c5bbcb2318daa82b'. Aborting the operation.
2021-06-22 15:34:35    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

I don't quite understand what's going on here, I'd use some help.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade sqlite 3.8.2 to >= 3.8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508830/how-to-upgrade-sqlite-3-8-2-to-3-8-3)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have already installed the freshest Python on my Windows 10 OS -> Python 3.9.5
I have downloaded the latest SQLite3 from official website (3.36). How can I make it reach 3.8.3 knowing that I already have the latest Python version ?