# I am trying to run "python manage.py runserver" for Django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

[image: 1] This is the error I got I tried changing the SQLite version Still it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade sqlite 3.8.2 to >= 3.8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508830/how-to-upgrade-sqlite-3-8-2-to-3-8-3)

Answer (score 0):

check your sqlite version and if its below 3.8, upgrade it